# color not changing in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I created a vector object from a drawing. But after I added the color, it will not change. I added it as a layer into my logo anyways. Now trying to change the color there but will not work.

After I press enter, nothing changes. Can you please tell me what I am not doing here. Screenshots appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The mistake above was attempting to change the color by picking a fill color.

Instead you can either select from the colors. Or if you are a web developer (as I am) you might want to enter the hex value directly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is selected.

You have to select something before you can change its color.

Comment: i edited the details in the post. Not sure what I am missing here though as I am click on it.